# What is the meaning of the option formatting in the rsync man page?

Tags: rsync, man

If you run `man rsync` and go to the options summary, there are alot of long form (i.e. `--long-option`) style options which are either an alias of, or grouped with a short form option. e.g.

OPTIONS SUMMARY
       Here is a short summary of the options available in rsync.

```
    -v, --verbose               increase verbosity
        --info=FLAGS            fine-grained informational verbosity
        --debug=FLAGS           fine-grained debug verbosity
        --msgs2stderr           special output handling for debugging 
    [...]
    -e, --rsh=COMMAND           specify the remote shell to use
        --rsync-path=PROGRAM    specify the rsync to run on remote machine
        --existing              skip creating new files on receiver
        --ignore-existing       skip updating files that exist on receiver
        --remove-source-files   sender removes synchronized files (non-dir)
        --del                   an alias for --delete-during
        --delete                delete extraneous files from dest dirs
        --delete-before         receiver deletes before xfer, not during
        --delete-during         receiver deletes during the transfer
        --delete-delay          find deletions during, delete after
        --delete-after          receiver deletes after transfer, not during
[...]
```

From this:

```
-v, --verbose               increase verbosity
```

I would take this to mean `-v` and `--verbose` are aliases of each other - i.e. they do they exact same thing.
But what about the other options e.g. in the case of verbose options

```
--info=FLAGS            fine-grained informational verbosity
--debug=FLAGS           fine-grained debug verbosity
```

and in the case of `-e`

```
--rsh=COMMAND`           specify the remote shell to use
--rsync-path=PROGRAM    specify the rsync to run on remote machine
--existing              skip creating new files on receiver
```

What is the relationship between the short form `-v`, `-e` and these long form options that seem to "belong" to the short form?
are they functionally related? e.g.
`--existing` can ONLY be used if it follows `-e`, like

```
rsync -e 'ssh ...' --existing
```

or does it mean `--existing` should NEVER be used with `-e`, in the same way that you wouldn't use `-v` if you already have `--verbose`.
Or is there no functional relationship whatsoever, i.e. the `--long-form` options which appear "grouped" with their short form parent are completely separate options in their own right and the `man rsync` authors have simply grouped them together for the sake of categorization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short form and the long form that are on the same line are the ones that are equivalent.

So, `-e COMMAND` is equivalent to `--rsh=COMMAND`, and `-v` is equivalent to `--verbose`.

The grouping of commands is by similarity of function, so `--verbose`, `--info`, and `--debug` are all related to the verbosity of the program as it runs. In this case, only `--verbose` has a short form equivalent, though.

Comment: thanks roaima,  do you know what the relationship is between the other long forms that are grouped with  the short form - long form aliases, e.g. `--info=FLAGS` , for verbose and `--rsync-path=PROGRAM` for `-e`?

Comment: ok I see, so they are bunched together that way so that when you think to yourself *"where are the rsync verbose options?*, you know where to look, and whether they are alternates of each other, mutually dependent or mutual exclusive commands is a whole different issue, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The lines that only have a long form option describes options that doesn't have a short form, they have nothing to do with any options described on previous lines. I.e. `--info` has nothing to do with `-v`/`--verbose`. The options are simply grouped by being somewhat similar, but rsync simply has too many options that they can all have a short form.